# " java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String "

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I see that this question has been asked many times, but I can't see where I've made this mistake.

I get this exception when I try to run my client class:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

```
public void errorReport() throws IOException
{
  File textFile = new File ("studentGPA_datafile.txt");
  Scanner errorScanFile = new Scanner (textFile);

  while (errorScanFile.hasNext())
  {
     int count = 1;
     count++;
     String fName = errorScanFile.next();
     String lName = errorScanFile.next();
     double studentGPA = errorScanFile.nextDouble();

     if (studentGPA >= 4.00 || studentGPA <= 0.00)
     {
        System.out.printf ("%15d %-15s %-15s %5.2f\n", count, lName, fName, studentGPA);
     }
  }
}
```

I thought that since it's a `d !=` error, the problem was with my display of `count` or `studentGPA`. But they seem to be right (d for int, f for double).

Comment: Why not use `System.out.println()` instead, and concatenate your variables using the `+` operator?

Comment: It doesn't look like that error came from the code you pasted.  Perhaps you need to recompile your source?  Also you probably intended to have the count outside of the while loop.